# Adding an absolute position button

Tags: ios, swift

I've seen apps that have a button (Blue button with a plus sign) on the lower right hand side of applications like the screenshot below:

[image]

My thought would be to have a UIView with an image.  The UIView will have a transparent background.  Wondering if anyone has experience with this?  If the main screen is a list will I be able to scroll through the list if there is a UIView on top?  Or is there a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be best to simply create a button on the ViewController's Storyboard. As long as you place it above your tableview / scrollview, it will not scroll with your content. Then you can make the button round quite easily with a little code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try.